# How to set up an array of objects properly for user inputed data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im setting up a gallery viewer that runs off rss feeds in javascript, i'm trying to lessen the burden of knowledge on the user of the application to as minimal as possible. There is a separate javascript file that holds all the custom data separately from the application, the array of objects is then extended by the default parameter object so that the user only has to enter what variables they want to change for each gallery, but a new object must be created for each to at least enter the rss path.

currently the default  variable looks some like

```
var default = { id:'x', path:"", row:1, col:5 (etc)}
```

I have set up the customVars script so the custom data is an array of objects that looks like this

```
var customVars = [

    albumList = { 
    path :"http://",                            
    displayType : "list"            
    },

    album1 = {
    path :   "http://",                         
    rows : 1 ,  col : 6         
    }
];
```

**EDIT(important)**- i need to be able to traverse the customVars data in an efficient manner, specifically when i dont know the name of the album objects they create- in other words, customVars[1].rows needs to be able to return 1

is this the proper way to accomplish this? am i going to run into weird errors down the line, or is there a better way to accomplish this maybe? is it ok to declare objects like that inside the array( i was trying to avoid having the user declare the variables and then have them set up the array themselves

**EDIT2**

changed it to an array of objects and added to variable id inside the parameter list, which seems to be working ok for now- still not sure if i can declare objects in this manner, but i need to be able to iterate through the list of objects

```
var customVars = [
{   
    id  : 'album0',
    path    : "https://",                           
    rssType : "picasaAlbum" ,   displayType : "list"            
},
{
    id  : 'album1',
    path    :"https://",                            
    rows    : 1 ,   collumns : 5        
}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare abc=something inside an array. You can rewrite it like this :

```
var customVars = [
{
    albumList: { 
        path :"http://",                            
        displayType : "list"            
    },

    album1: {
        path :   "http://",                         
        rows : 1 ,  col : 6         
    }
},
{
    albumList: { 
        path :"http://",                            
        displayType : "list"            
    },

    album1: {
        path :   "http://",                         
        rows : 1 ,  col : 6         
    }
}]
```

;

This is a proper inline javascript object creation, even if many think it's json :)

Comment: i tried it like this, but i need to be able to traverse it like an array, something like customVars[1].rows was throwing up errors

Comment: @user667122 - you can use `for(item in customVars) {}` to iterate through the object (only thing is unlike a standard for loop with an array the order of iteration may not be what you expect).

Answer (score 0):

I think a much more readable and maintainable structure would be to use an object instead of an array. Something like:

```
var customVars = {
      albumList : { path :"http://",
                    displayType : "list" 
                  },
      album1 :    { path : "http://",
                    rows : 1,
                    col : 6
                  }
};
```

I've never seen the syntax that you used to declare variables at the same time as including them in an array. I guess it will work (I can't be bothered trying it; I assume you have already) since each array element is still an expression, but I don't like it because I think it could be confusing during future maintenance, and also it would create `albumList` and `album1` as global variables. I would (almost) never declare variables without the `var` statement, even when I *want* them to be global, because it becomes too easy to introduce hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an actual array inside your Object? If you're going to have a list of something you should use an array so you can iterate over them.

```
var customVars = {
  albumList : { 
    path :"http://",
    displayType : "list",
    albums:[{
             name:"album1:,
             path : "http://",
             rows : 1,
             col : 6                   
            },
            {
             name:"album2:,
             path : "http://",
             rows : 1,
             col : 6                   
            }
    ]}   
};
```